# How to execute a block of code when a certain fragment is shown?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I've set up a pager with 3 fragments, I want to execute an specific block of code when fragment #2 is shown but problem is that onCreate/onResume methods from this fragment execute when fragment #1 is shown. I understand that the logic behind this is doing work ahead for when fragment#2 is actually needed, but how can I do if I need something to be done specifically when fragment#2 is shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement an [`OnPageChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html), override [`OnPageSelected`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html#onPageSelected(int)) and set it on the `ViewPager` this way:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if (position == 1) { // Meaning the position of the 2nd Fragment
            doSomeCode();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
});
```